# Having trouble understanding how to resolve a promise inside a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to Promises and I'm having trouble resolving this problem. I have a basic function that essentially fetches some JSON using Axios:

```
function getData () {

  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function (response) {
      var payload = response.data
      return payload;
    }).catch(function (response) {
      return 'Promise Error'
  }) 
}
```

If I invoke `getData()` from another function, the payload keeps coming back `undefined`.

```
(function getJSON () {

  var returnedPayload = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    var payload = getData();

    resolve(payload)      
    reject('Something went wrong')
  })

  returnedPayload.then(
    console.log(payload)
  ).catch(
    'Something went wrong'
  )

  console.log(returnedPayload)

})();
```

I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here, but I'm really not sure how to construct a promise within a promise...

Comment: Perhaps `return axios.get...`?

Comment: @thefourtheye that worked for me. I’ll have to do some research to figure out why that works. Thanks!